# How can I select columns in R?

Tags: r, select, logistic-regression

I am trying to do logistic reasoning in R. Suppose I have columns from A to I (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I). Now I want to assign Z to data frame which has columns A,B,C,D,G,H. How will I do the same in R?

Comment: You can do `df1[c(1:4, 6:7)]`

Comment: Combine them how? Are these 2 data frames that you want to join, or column-bind, or some other operation? Try to build a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can help with more specifically, because right now it's pretty unclear what exactly you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

We can use numeric indexing to select the columns

```
df1[c(1:4, 6:7)]
```

---

If we need two datasets, use `setdiff` to select column names that we don't need

```
df2 <- df1["A"]
df3 <- df1[setdiff(names(df1), "A")]
```

Comment: Is there any way, that if I need to assign df2 to data frame having column A and another data frame (say df3) containing rest of the columns?